# No puedo mostrar lectura de sensor de arduino en mi interfaz, se bloquea

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de crear una interfaz gráfica en tkinter para mostrar la lectura de un sensor en una placa Arduino uno.

El error es que cuando corro el programa se queda en el ciclo `While` y la ventana en blanco, cuando le doy interrumpir me muestra en el Label sensor un este error `PY_VARO()`

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import serial 
import sys
import numpy as np
import pylab as ventana


serie = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600) # Lectura del puerto serie de arduino con la lib serial

def sensor_tem(): # funcion para leer el sensor


    while 1: # inicio el Bucle

        #print(serie.readline())

        dato = serie.readline() # Lectura del sensor

        senso = dato[0:1]           
        readingt.set(senso)
        #ventana.sensor_tem()
        sleep(1)

#readingt = StringVar()

ventana = Tk()# inicia la ventana
ventana.geometry("600x300+0+0")  # Tamaño de ventana

ventana.title("Sensor Temperatura") # Titulo de ventana

tit_sensor = Label(ventana, text = "Lectura Sensor").place(x = 100, y = 70)
readingt = StringVar() # convierto la variable a String
 #muestro la lectura del sensor en el Label.
sensor = Label(ventana, text= readingt).place(x= 100, y = 100)
btn_salir = Button(ventana, text = " Salir", command = exit).place(x = 100, y = 130)

ventana.after(1, sensor_tem)#actualizo la ventana
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en el código que voy a intentar explicar:

❶ El problema principal que causa el bloqueo de la GUI es el uso de un ciclo infinito (`while 1`). Cuando llamas a la función por primera vez (y última) se entra en el ciclo tomando el control del hilo principal y ya no se sale de el por lo que no se le da la oportunidad a la GUI de actualizarse y se bloquea. Además, nunca debes usar `sleep()` en el hilo principal de una aplicación `Tkinter` ya que también es bloqueante.

La solución es usar `after()` y llamar recursivamente a la función. Por otro lado, si solo requieres actualizar el `label`, puedes aplicar el `after()` sobre el y no sobre toda la ventana. La idea general es algo asi:

```
def funcion():
    #hacer algo
    label.after(1000, funcion) 

sensor.after(1000, funcion)
```

De esta forma se crea el mismo efecto de un ciclo infinito pero en este caso no es bloqueante.

---

❷ Por otro lado, la forma correcta de conseguir el contenido de `StringVar` es usando el método `get()`. No obstante es mucho más sencillo indicarle al `label` que tome el texto de una variable mediante el atributo `textvariable`. De esta forma cada vez que la variable cambie, automáticamente (ya que en realidad es un evento) cambia el contenido del `Label`:

```
readingt = StringVar()
sensor = Label(ventana, textvariable = readingt)
```

---

❸ Es muy común hacer esto:

```
sensor = Label(ventana, textvariable = readingt).place(x= 100, y = 100)
```

Lo cual funciona pero luego nos encontramos con errores al intentar hacer por ejemplo:

```
label.after(1000, funcion)
```

El problema de usar el método `place()` en la misma linea es que ahora `sensor` no es un objeto `Label` como podriamos pensar, es en realidad el retorno de `place()`, es decir `None`. Por esta razón es siempre oportuno aplicar `place` en una línea diferente:

```
sensor = Label(ventana, textvariable = readingt)
sensor.place(x= 100, y = 100)
```

---

❹ Estas importando `pylab` como `ventana` y luego creas una aplicación con `Tkinter` llamándola también `ventana`, lo cual sobreescribe lo anterior. Esto realmente no causa problemas por ahora pero si luego vas a usar `pylab` después vas a tener problemas. Por ejemplo si intentas usar el método `linspace()` de `pylabel`, lo llamarias así:

```
t = ventana.linspace(-pl.pi, pl.pi, 10000)
```

esto ocasiona un error:

> AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'linspace'

porque ventana es una instancia de `tkinter.Tk` en realidad. Cambia el `import` a algo como:

```
import pylab as pl
```

❺ Por último, el método `readline()` es bloqueante, no retorna nada hasta que exista algo que leer, lo cual puede ser nunca. Esto bloquea la GUI igualmente, para que esto no pase especificamos que no espere a que exista una lectura:

```
serie = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)
```

---

El código deberia quedar así:

```
from tkinter import *
import serial 
import sys
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl



serie = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)

def sensor_tem():
    dato = serie.readline()
    senso = dato[0:1]   
    readingt.set(senso)
    sensor.after(1000, sensor_tem)



ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x300+0+0")
ventana.title("Sensor Temperatura")

tit_sensor = Label(ventana, text = "Lectura Sensor")
tit_sensor.place(x = 100, y = 70)

readingt = StringVar()

sensor = Label(ventana, textvariable = readingt)
sensor.place(x= 100, y = 100)

btn_salir = Button(ventana, text = " Salir", command = exit)
btn_salir.place(x = 100, y = 130)

sensor.after(1000, sensor_tem)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Un apunte, `after()` recibe el tiempo de espera en **milisegundos**, yo he puesto 1000 que sería un segundo. Puedes cambiarlo pero ten en cuenta que 1 milisegundo como lo tienes tu puede ser una carga importante para el procesador y puede no aportar demasiada información útil.

Existen otras formas de abordar estos problemas como es el uso de hilos y colas pero para tu caso esto funciona correctamente y es más simple.

**EDICIÖN:**

Añado ejemplo usando hilos y una cola:

```
import serial
import threading
import time
import queue
import tkinter as tk


class readerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        serie = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)

        while True:
            datos = serie.readline()
            senso = datos[0:1]
            if senso:
                self.queue.put(senso)
            time.sleep(1)

class sensorGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("600x300+0+0")
        self.title("Sensor Temperatura")

        self.tit_sensor = tk.Label(self, text = "Lectura Sensor")
        self.tit_sensor.place(x = 100, y = 70)

        self.readingt = tk.StringVar()

        self.sensor = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.readingt)
        self.sensor.place(x= 100, y = 100)

        self.btn_salir = tk.Button(self, text = " Salir", command = self.salir)
        self.btn_salir.place(x = 100, y = 130)

        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        thread = readerThread(self.queue)
        thread.start()
        self.actualizar_datos()

    def actualizar_datos(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                self.readingt.set(self.queue.get())
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
        self.after(100, self.actualizar_datos)

    def salir(self):
        self.destroy()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = sensorGUI()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, pero el código sigue ciclando y no captura la lectura del sensor.

Comment: ¿La GUI se bloquea o simplemente no muestra la lectura? El código funciona a no ser que el problema esté en la lectura del sensor en si y del manejo de la biblioteca serial. Esto no lo puedo reproducir porque no tengo a mano una placa Arduino. Aporta más información si es posible.

Comment: Gracia as Fjsevilla, la GUI se bloquea  y no muestra la lectura del sensor..  No invoca la Función.. Pero no he logrado solucionarlo...

Comment: La GUI funciona perfectamente, el problema ahora que lo pienso puede estar en que se tarde demasiado en leer la información del puerto o que directamente no sea capz de leer de el. Prueba a cambiar: `serie = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)`, por `serie = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)` para asegurate de que la lectura es no bloqueante. Tambien puedes intentar ver por consola si el puerto remite la información o no.

Comment: Mirando la documentacion de `pyserial` se puede ver que `Serial.readline() ` **no retorna nada** hasta que no **exista alguna línea que retornar**, lo cual puede que sea nunca. Si tu dispositivo no escribe ninguna línea  la función se queda esperando infinitamente y eso bloquea la GUI.

Comment: Por consola siempre me ha funcionado, por esto lo quería migrar a una GUI para que se mostrara mas agradable al ojo... He utilizado serie = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=1)

Comment: Si te sigue sin funcionar @JJRestrepo he editado la respuesta para hacer una implementación usando hilos (al final de la respuesta está el nuevo código). Prueba a ver si te funciona así. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. Con hilos no funciona.. Pero solucine el error con el timeout=0.  Ya lo provare configurando los otros sensores... Feliz día por  tu ayuda...

Comment: estaba usando el segundo codigo que colocaste pero al abrir la ventana no me da el dato del sensor te temperatura lo unico que muestra es un "T"...

Answer (score 0):

Tengo este fallo al ejecutar el último código con thread y queue. No me deja ejecutar el programa.

He probado a modificar esa línea por  self.queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=0).

Pero me sigue dando el fallo ¿Cual es la solución?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Usuario Windows\Escritorio\GUI\queue_thread\queue1.py", line 58, in 
    app = sensorGUI()
  File "E:\Usuario Windows\Escritorio\GUI\queue_thread\queue1.py", line 41, in **init**
    self.queue = queue.Queue()
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'Queue'
[Finished in 0.2s]